# Sphinx Alabaster theme TOC not showing in all pages

Tags: python-sphinx, sidebar, navigationbar, toctree

I am trying to have the TOC show up in all my pages. My set up is pretty simple. In the index.rst, I have

```
Installation
============

Scripting
=========


.. toctree::
:maxdepth: 2
:caption: Contents:

class ASAT
""""""""""
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2

    asat

    more class ...
```

and in the other pages, I have:

```
class asat.SomeClass
"""""""""""""""""""""
.. autoclass:: modeule.SomeClass
    :members:

    .. automethod:: __init__
```

In order for the TOC to appear, I changed `conf.py` to reflect:

```
html_sidebars = {
    '**': [
        'globaltoc.html',
        'relations.html',
        'searchbox.html'
    ]
}
```

But in doing so, none of the nested stuff from `index.rst` is showing up in any of the TOCs. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image: Imgur]

How can I get the original/normal TOC from alabaster to appear in all my pages?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [installation docs](https://alabaster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), you need to add `navigation.html` to the setting.

```
html_sidebars = {
    '**': [
        'about.html',
        'navigation.html',
        'relations.html',
        'searchbox.html',
        'donate.html',
    ]
}
```

If you are using a variant of Alabaster, consult their documentation.

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that your reStructuredText syntax is incorrect.  You need to indent the parameters for `toctree`.

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2
    :caption: Contents:
```

Comment: that mostly solves the issue. Now the TOC appears for the individual pages, but not that of the index or any other pages besides on the main page.

Comment: Most likely due to the index page being generated before. You can trigger a rebuild of a specific file by deleting it from the build directory, or rebuild the entire docs with `make clean html`. Please let me know if that fixes the last issue.

Comment: Ah yes, when i copied it over, i pasted the toc tree incorrectly. My toc is set correctly otherwise sphinx would throw an error. my issue still remains. i tried studying the raw files from the alabaster theme itself, but cant see what he/she is doing differently. while we are on the topic of sphinx, would you be able to address another question? how can i make the methods of a class show up on the side bar while using `.. autoclass`? currently, only the class name shows up on the sidebar

Comment: At this point, you should create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a repo that we can clone and use to reproduce the issue. For the new issue, you should create a new separate question, but first search through SO for an answer. I've seen this question asked.

Comment: Same issue here with the Sphinx autogenerated index.rst. Nothing shows up in the navigation section with alabaster, while rtd works.